# VBScript Legacy Pack required when only using Bundle Workflow

Tags: workflow, 2013-sp1-hr1

In my environment (SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1) I have a workflow environment set-up and we only use Bundle Workflow.

I'm getting the following dialog message when I attempt to save a component based on a specific schema.

> Workflow Script Type with Name 'VBScript' was not found in the configuration file

The log message is:

```
Workflow Script Type with Name 'VBScript' was not found in the configuration file.
  Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService Errorcode: 885 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE  StackTrace Information Details:
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Workflow.ScriptContentHandler.GetScriptContentHandler(String scriptType)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Workflow.TridionActivityDefinition.ReplaceReferencesUsingScriptContentHandler(Session session, TridionActivityDefinitionData activity, String script, String scriptType, Boolean useWebDavUrls)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Workflow.TridionProcessDefinition.OnLoaded(LoadEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Load(LoadFlags flags, Boolean forceReload)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Load(LoadFlags flags)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.GetProcessDefinitionInternal(ProcessDefinitionType processDefinitionType)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component.GetProcessDefinition(ProcessDefinitionType processDefinitionType)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.GetProcessDefinitionsForItems(IEnumerable`1 itemIds, ProcessDefinitionType processDefinitionType)
   at SyncInvokeGetProcessDefinitionsForItems(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

I note from other questions and general documentation that I should not require the Legacy Pack sa I'm only using workflow bundles. Further to this I don't require it in another environment.

I've since replicated the schema and then also the contents (linking the same components etc.) but not managed to replicate this - I've removed my event code etc. but am still seeing the error on saving component(s) based on the original schema. Any ideas of where to investigate next?

### Update

I was able to replicate the issue when I check (as we want longer-term)

> Any changes made to a Component based on this Schema require approval
>   by a Bundle Workflow Process

- The Associated Component Process is *(None)* in both cases and
- Preferred Workflow Process for this Bundle in *Component Process*.

This does seem ironic given we only want to use Bundle Workflow and now we want to enforce it we're triggering a need for the Legacy Pack?

Comment: Which activities do you have on a Process Definition associated with schema? From the error it says that one of the Automatic Activity definitions has VBscript workflow script type.

Comment: The Legacy pack is not need for bundle workflow. It is needed by process definition associated to your Preferred Workflow Process

Comment: Hey Stan - it was essentially the Preferred Workflow Process setting to a legacy item - which was acnkoneldged/tested when the schema setting to force bundle workflow is set! If you promote your comment to an answer I'm happy to mark it up :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error it says that one of the Automatic Activity definitions has VBscript workflow script type.

Please check Activity Definitions on Preferred Workflow Process process definition.